# jQuery Plugins Doesn't Work Well with Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs

i have used **jQuery slider** in my project in which i am loading images using angular. My current view looks like this;

```
        <div id="slides">
            <div class="slides_container">
                <a href="" data-ng-repeat="image in gallery">
                    <img data-ng-src="{{image.imageUrl}}" width="919" height="326" alt="" />
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

the controller;

```
blogApp.controller("HomeController", ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
    var basePath = '/api/',
        FrontGallery = $resource(basePath + 'gallery?culture=en-US'),

    $scope.gallery = FrontGallery.query();
}]);
```

And the jQuery slider code (to make it a slider. I'm using this plugin http://archive.slidesjs.com/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: '/content/images/theme/loading.gif',
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        hoverPause: true
    });
});
```

When, i try this code, my all images are loaded from database (debugged it through firebug) **but jQuery slider isn't applying the animation or sliding effect to it** 
And when i remove the `data-ng-repeat="image in gallery` and use Some static content i.e images, i get the sliding effect back.
What's the problem here. I think Angular is manipulating some how my DOM. That's why i'm getting this problem whenever i put i.e use some angular attributes on my slider.

**Note:** i have the same issue with jQuery news i.e jQuery `InnerFade` plugin http://medienfreunde.com/lab/innerfade/ 
Here is how the `innerFade` is used;

```
<h1>
    <img src="/content/images/theme/hotnews.png" alt="" />Hot News</h1>
<ul id="news">
    <li class="ng-repeat:headline in news">
        <span class="ng-bind:headline.description"></span>
        <a href="#" title="Read More">» more</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

and the controller;

```
var HotNews = $resource(basePath + 'article/hotnews?culture=en-US');
$scope.news = HotNews.query();
```

**How do i fix these problems?**
**Update 2:**
Here is my routes;

```
// declare a module
var blogApp = angular
    .module('blogApp', ['ngResource', 'ngSanitize'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        //configure the routes
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                // list the home page
                templateUrl: "tmpl/home.html",
                controller: "HomeController"
            })
            .when('/article/:id', {
                // access custom param
                foo: "hello world",
                // list the home page
                templateUrl: "tmpl/article.html",
                controller: "ArticleController"
            })
            .when('/404', {
                template: '<h1>404 Not Found!</h1>'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/404' });
    }]);
```

**Solution #1:**
Temporary, (As **@Jason Goemaat** answered) works for me. So, here is what i have done. I didn't create any `directive` but straightly i injected the `$timeout` to my controller and then i did the following;

```
$timeout(function () {
    jQuery('#news').innerfade({
        animationtype: 'slide',
        speed: 750,
        timeout: 2000,
        type: 'random',
        containerheight: '1em'
    });
    jQuery('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: 'image/theme/loading.gif',
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        hoverPause: true
    });

}, 100);
```

And it did work for both i.e for `Slider` and for `InnerFade`

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle or similar, I would try to write a directive to fix that ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular IS manipulating your dom, the ng-repeat directive is creating the elements when it has a list to work from.  Because of that you need to call `.slides` after angular is done creating the elements because that plugin is altering the DOM itself.

Here's a directive you can use to call `$.slides` on an element based on when an array has length > 0.  It shows using extra attributes like 'start' to modify the call to slides too.  Here it checks an array on your $scope called 'images' and calls `$timeout()` during the link phase to call `.slidesjs()` when angular is done creating the DOM.  I didn't know what plugin you used so I found one called '[slidesjs](http://slidesjs.com/) that looked similar.  'Here's a plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/4qdUctYMIpd8WqEg0OiO?p=preview

Html:

```
<div my-slides="images" start="4">
  <img ng-repeat="image in images" ng-src="{{image.url}}" />
</div>
```

Directive:

```
app.directive('mySlides', function() {
  var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.mySlides, function(value) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          // only if we have images since .slidesjs() can't
          // be called more than once
          if (value.length > 0) {
            $(element[0]).slidesjs({
              preload: true,
              preloadImage: '/content/images/theme/loading.gif',
              play: attrs.play || 5000,
              pause: attrs.pause || 2500,
              start: attrs.start || 1,
              hoverPause: attrs.hoverPause || true,
              navigation: { active: true, effect: "slide" }
            });
          }
        }, 1);
      });
    }
  };
  return directive;
});
```

One thing to note is that it still can only be called once, so if your image list gets updated it won't work.  To do that you could create the content in the directive...

Comment: the data is comming from database like this=> `FrontGallery = $resource(basePath + 'gallery?culture=en-US');    
$scope.gallery = FrontGallery.query();`

Comment: You don't need to, the call to $scope.$watch will call the function you pass whenever the value, gallery in this case, changes.

Comment: did you wrap the jQuery call in a timeout?  At the point $watch executes the function the elements might not be created yet...

Comment: no, i didn't. should i use $timoute as well. If yes, can you provide a little more descriptive answer

Comment: timeout fix the problem for innerFade, but is it really the good solution to this problem or the recommended?

Comment: I will perhaps sound like a jerk but putting jquery or DOM stuff in a controller should not be marked as a solution. You can use $timeout in directives, and if your timeout callback don't change the model (don't need angular to digest changes) you can just use setTimeout.

Comment: @Guillaume86 you are right. This kind of logic does not belong in the controller. Its should be an angular directive.

Comment: Totally agree, just wanted to get at the root of what was causing his problem, i.e. calling jquery before dom elements were created...

Comment: i also don't agree with this answer but it solve the problem and it is temporary, i know that @Fresheyeball's answer is best but i'm trying to solve it using directive

Answer (score 9):

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
```

is firing before angular has loaded the content onto the page. The jQuery slider script should only be activated after angular has loaded the content. Part of the problem here is that angular does not provide a callback for `$digest` so you don't have an event to listen for.

The content load -> event callback -> ui build, while common in jQuery and standard javascript thinking, its not part of the angular mentality. Luckily angular has an insanely powerful method for handling this problem.

What you need is to turn the jQuery slideshow script into an angular [directive](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). Then it will become part of the angular process space and get instantiated as a part of the angular digest cycle.

Something like

```
   <div id="slides" my-slideshow >
        <div class="slides_container">
            <a href="" data-ng-repeat="image in gallery">
                <img data-ng-src="{{image.imageUrl}}" width="919" height="326" alt="" />
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Good luck!

---

Happy example time using innerfade (I have not tested this yet, will do ASAP). First your application must declare an angular module if it doesn't already. `ng-app="myModule"`. http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.module

(make sure your controller is attached as well!)

Now you can declare a directive on that module. Which is super cool.

```
angular.module('myModule').directive("innerFade", function () {
   var res = {
     restrict : 'C',
     link     : function (scope, element, attrs) {
           scope.$watch(attrs.innerFade, function(){             
               element.innerfade({
                  speed: 'slow',
                  timeout: 1000,
                  type: 'sequence',
                  containerheight: '1.5em'
               });
           });
        }
     };
  return res;
});
```

The way this works is pretty simple. The `$watch` function will monitor the part of scope containing your data. When that changes (including initialization), it will fire the `innerfade` jQuery function on the `element` with the directive. We are also passing 'C' to the restrict argument so this custom directive will be a class only directive (I noticed you seem to like that).

```
 <ul class="inner-fade:innerData" >
      <li class="ng-repeat:fadeItem in innerData">{{fadeItem}}</li>
 </ul>
```

Now all you have to do is bind the data to `$scope.innerData` in your controller (bind it any way you like including ajax), and it will just work. You can even change the data on `$scope.innerData` and it will update with full jQuery glory.

Comment: I can transform it into a directive, but I don't have the time right now to do the work and test it for delivery as a completed code. Plus it better to just learn how the angular ecosystem works anyway. It should not be too hard, and more than worth knowing.

Comment: @DotNetDreamer if you end up going with the custom directive approach, don't forget to accept this answer.

Comment: Hey, so I noticed you opened up a bounty on this one. Whats up? Did the custom directive direction not work out for you?

Comment: no dear, the problem is i don't understand the `directives` completly. I tried different directives aproach but it didn't work

Comment: i have 4 other developers here, if you can proivde the answer, they will also give +1s, becuase they have this problem too

Comment: Can you link me to the slider pluggin you are using?

Comment: thanks for your time dear. I have no clue right now that which gallery prlugin are they (the designer) using and i'm not at that office right now. Hoever, i have provided the link and the example of a plugin called `jQuery InnerFade` (see the last portion of the question). If you solve the `Innerfade` issue, I'll try the same thing for the gallery too;

Comment: your solution is working only if i force the browser by `Ctrl+F5`. If i come back from another route to the homepage(the same page) again, the effect isn't applied

Comment: and  i also updated the question. I'm using `http://archive.slidesjs.com/` plugin

Comment: @DotNetDreamer can you post more information about your setup regarding routes? Its sounds like you just need the jQuery to fire on route changes as well as scope update (no way for me to know that). Also I've answered your question and explained how this is supposed to work with angular. I think at some point it comes down to that you need to learn more and develop skills in angular, and it stops being a stack overflow question.

Comment: @DotNetDreamer when you change routes does other data display? You might be missing a `$apply()` somewhere.

Comment: yeah, let's suppose, i have route `#/` (which is the hope page. Gallery and InnerFade effect is applied here). When i navigate from `#/` to `#/Content` and then come back from `#/Content` to `#/`, the effect isn't applied. I guess the problem is caching because when i press `Ctrl+f5`, it start working again

Comment: You need to be triggering a digest cycle on route change regardless. In other words the jquery powered directives are working as they are supposed to. Your routes have a seporate problem.

Comment: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider comment #1 I believe might have your answer.

Comment: @Jason Goemaat solution works for me. i also tried injecting `$route` to controller but still didn't succeed. Temporary `$timeoute` works for me

Comment: Just as a curiosity, did you try using timeout inside the directive?

Answer (score 1):

A few thoughts
1) My guess is that there is something sequentially wrong with your main app page. Do you have jQuery include **after** angularjs? I assume you are using ng-repeat directive?

2) change $ to jQuery

3) place document.ready script in main page ... also consider replacing it with

```
 window.onload=function(){}
```

I am sure I can debug if you can show code for main page as well as the view.

Comment: this is working but in `Firefox, Chrome`, when i press the `Ctrl+f5` key. However, when i simply `Refresh` the browser (without ctrl+f5), then it's not working. And in `IE` it doesn't work at all

Comment: And also, if i come back from another route, the behavior isn't applied

Comment: i put `alert("It's loaded!");` inside the `window.onload`, i don't see any alert when i come back fron another route.

Comment: Regarding IE - try adding this line in the header: id="ng-app". Anyway,lets cut to the chase and get this thing done for you! Give me access to all the code and I will rewrite for you and provide detailed comments and explanations for future reference.

Comment: that's really appreciated. but how can i send my files to you

Comment: Drop me a separate email to doug.deloy@sbcgobal.net and and I will provide you with FTP access to upload appropriate files to my domain. I will make some modifications - and create working prototype which you can readily follow. Form there it will be up to you to take ownership of the solution selectively apply modifications that are consistent with the overall structure of your application. I look forward to the challenge and also to seeing the end result of our collaborative efforts! :::)

Answer (score 1):

Add a directive to #slides

```
app.directive("slideDirective", function () {
     return function (scope, element, attrs) {
         // Dom
         element.slides({
             preload: true,
             preloadImage: '/content/images/theme/loading.gif',
             play: 5000,
             pause: 2500,
             hoverPause: true
         });
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? This is how I implemented another jQuery script that needed a doc ready function.

Comment: i first created a directive like above and then i call it like this; `<div id="slider" slide-directive>`. However, i don't see any changes. I know that the best solution to this problem is `directives` but i'm new to angular and directives are a little far from me

Comment: You need to use a timeout so that .slides is called after angular is done manipulating the dom

Comment: @JasonGoemaat this is exactly what helped in my case (bxSlider-plugin)

Answer (score 1):

as it was said: "The jQuery slider script should only be activated after angular has loaded the content"
So you can wait before it will be loaded, and then your jQuery code will start running.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
setTimeout(function(){
      $('#slides').slides({
        preload: true,
        preloadImage: '/content/images/theme/loading.gif',
        play: 5000,
        pause: 2500,
        hoverPause: true
     });
}, 10);
});
```

Comment: What garanties do you have that the page will take 10ms to load? It depends the conection.